# How to change the <hr> size and center it of a div?

Tags: html, css

```css
hr {
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  background-color:#888;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
              <h3> News</h3>
              <h4>The New Concept</h4>
              <p>While files form the internet can be useful , this file type can prote....</p>
              <div class="read-more">
                <a href="#">Read more news</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 news">
              <h3> News</h3>
              <h4>The New Concept</h4>
              <p>While files form the internet can be useful , this file type can prote....</p>
              <div class="read-more">
                <a href="#">Read more news</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3 id="ebook">Hot e-Book</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would like to make this webpage more clear and want to change the hr line width size so it will looks like same width as above div area.

However, I tried few times and did not work well so I come here to see if anyone can help me?

Please review it in full page because responsive desgin.
How to change the hr line size and make its width as col-sm-6 + col-sm-4?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier/better to use the border bottom of the div, or the top of the one below to achieve this? Especially if you want to use `<hr>` in other places as well.

Comment: Because there are two divs above, so can not set border-bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `hr` with a div and center it.

```css
hr {
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  background-color:#888;
}
#div-center{
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
              <h3> News</h3>
              <h4>The New Concept</h4>
              <p>While files form the internet can be useful , this file type can prote....</p>
              <div class="read-more">
                <a href="#">Read more news</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 news">
              <h3> News</h3>
              <h4>The New Concept</h4>
              <p>While files form the internet can be useful , this file type can prote....</p>
              <div class="read-more">
                <a href="#">Read more news</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10" id="div-center">
      <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3 id="ebook">Hot e-Book</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
hr {
 margin-left: 8.3%; 
margin-right: 8.3%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1">
              <h3> News</h3>
              <h4>The New Concept</h4>
              <p>While files form the internet can be useful , this file type can prote....</p>
              <div class="read-more">
                <a href="#">Read more news</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 news">
              <h3> News</h3>
              <h4>The New Concept</h4>
              <p>While files form the internet can be useful , this file type can prote....</p>
              <div class="read-more">
                <a href="#">Read more news</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3 id="ebook">Hot e-Book</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove class="row" section and give width as you want 50%, 70% etc.